# How can I customize jquery.parallax.min.js parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax

I am using Pond Html template to make simple portfolio site (http://ag.orchidaceaeurbantribal.com), and trying to customize jquery.parallax parameters to zoom image a little bit out:

```
if(jQuery().parallax) { 
    jQuery('.parallax-section').parallax();
}
```

But it looks like any parameter I send to parallax function is not applying at all. Maybe anyone had anything similar? 
Thanks in advance for help .